# Android MediaRecorder audio recording starts with delay?

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I am using **[MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html)** to record audio in my Android application.

My earlier steps were, as follows :

> 1] Play beep sound,  ( Way of notifying user recording has started )
>
> 2] Prepare recorder by passing file reference,
>
> 3] Call start() method of recorder,
>
> 4] Above step 2 & 3 called only after listening the beep play completion using **[MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html)**

Then after testing I observed, If I say `"Hello World ! How are you ?"` the whole `"Hello World"` part was missing from recording, then I changed my steps as follows :

> 1] Prepare recorder by passing file reference,
>
> 2] Play beep sound, ( Way of notifying user recording has started )
>
> 3] Call start() method of recorder by listening the beep play completion using **[MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html)**

Now the delay has been minimized but still, Missing `"Hello"` word in the recording, i.e. small delay still exists.

The documentation of MediaRecorder start() does not specify any such delay.

What can I do to eliminate the delay in start of recording ? How I can be sure of point in time where recording is really started ?

Comment: Faced the same problem, apparently you cant have that kind of precision with MediaRecorder, better go with AudioRecord API. for some device the delay is 50-120 milliseconds and for some device that will be in excess of 700 milliseconds. the if you are recording audio and video both then there will simply be silence appended before the actual audio data appears to compensate for delay. best bet is to start your recorder 1 second before the start of MediaPlayer.